# expo-auth-session fetchUserInfoAsync -> invalid token error

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development, expo-auth-session

Package `expo-auth-session`: We are using Azure sso for our authentication, and we are able to get the token after logging in.

**The problem:** However if we try to use the `fetchUserInfoAsync(responseExchangeCode, discovery)` method, it returns an invalid token error.

Alternative Package `react-native-msal`: If however we use this package, we are able to get the user information in the response of it's method `acquireToken(aqcuireTokenParams)`. We can't use this plugin though due to conflict issues it has with microsoft auth app on ios devices. But it does retrieve all the user info.

App.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import {
  exchangeCodeAsync,
  fetchUserInfoAsync,
  makeRedirectUri,
  Prompt,
  useAuthRequest,
  useAutoDiscovery,
} from 'expo-auth-session';
import { Button, Text, SafeAreaView, Platform } from 'react-native';


WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
const clientId = '<my_client_id>';
const redirectUri = makeRedirectUri({
  path: Platform.select({
    android: 'com.example/<my_decrypted_hash_value>',
    ios: 'com.example://auth',
    default: undefined
  })
});


export default function App() {
  // Endpoint
  const discovery = useAutoDiscovery('https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant_id>/v2.0');

  // Request
  const [request, , promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      prompt: Prompt.Login,
      clientId,
      scopes: ['https://www.example.com/API.All'],
      redirectUri,
    },
    discovery,
  );

  // functions
  const login = async () => {
    try {
      const propmtResponse = await promptAsync();
      if (request && propmtResponse?.type === 'success' && discovery) {
        const responseExchangeCode = await exchangeCodeAsync(
          {
            clientId,
            code: propmtResponse.params.code,
            extraParams: request.codeVerifier
              ? { code_verifier: request.codeVerifier }
              : undefined,
            redirectUri,
          },
          discovery,
        );
        console.log('responseExchangeCode:', responseExchangeCode); // has token
        const userInfo = await fetchUserInfoAsync(responseExchangeCode, discovery); // <------------- Error happens here
        console.log('userInfo:', userInfo);
      } else {
        throw new Error('something went wrong');
      }
    } catch(error: any) {
      console.log('error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Button
        disabled={!request}
        title="Login"
        onPress={login}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My App",
    "slug": "My-App",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scheme": "msauth",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.example",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.example",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

## Results

[image]